# How to prevent axios to show request url and response data in console and network tab of browser?

Tags: laravel-5, axios, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt and laravel in my project and using axios to send http request into the backend server. The problem is that whenever a request is made and data is returned the console and network tab of browser by default shows the url where request has been made and the data returned from the url. How can I prevent the console and network tab from showing these details as it is creating security issues in the application?

I have already tried with debug: false in axios module of nuxt.config.js file and same in .env file of laravel

In nuxt.config.js file
axios: {
        proxyHeaders: false,
    credentials: false,
    proxy: false,
    debug: false
},
In .env file of laravel
APP_DEBUG=false

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to prevent it, even in you will do it it will not stop normal hackers from stealing your data, looks like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089165/how-to-hide-request-from-network-tab) can help you,
but much better will be to use https and do not rely on browser console visibility.